# TCPDF problems cause some data has been already outputted

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

When I'm using TCPDF sometimes I cant send pdf file because there has been some data outputted.
But there are no errors.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

The Answer is:
Simply add an ob_start() to the top of your script and an ob_clean() 
before your using TCPDF::Output()